# Regex to match custom key pair not working in linux

Tags: regex, linux

I have custom key pair as arguments passed to linux script. key value pairs can be any in number. I need to validate whether the key pair is in proper order or not. I am not able to fully implement it.

```
argumentz="[some_key=some_value]  [some_key2=some_value2]"
pair_format="^([[:blank:]]*\[[[:blank:]]*[^=]+[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*[^=]+[[:blank:]]*\][[:blank:]]*)+$"
if [[ ! $argumentz =~ $pair_format ]]; then
echo "format mismatch"
else
echo "match"
fi
```

The above pair_format is failing to detect below mistake where square brace should be avoided.

```
argumentz="[ab_cd=ef] [[gh=ij]"
```

When pair_format is modified to below, to exclude [] along with = its not working when valid arguments are given.

```
pair_format="^([[:blank:]]*\[[[:blank:]]*[^=\[\]]+[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*[^=\[\]]+[[:blank:]]*\][[:blank:]]*)+$"
```

Please help.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you. Not sure why, but this method isn't still working. Of course the same being proposed in the origincal question link you mentioned. Still no luck for me.

Comment: Ok, it works if you  use `pair_format='^[[:blank:]]*(\[[[:blank:]]*[^]=[]+[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*[^]=[]+[[:blank:]]*][[:blank:]]*)+$'`, see [demo](https://ideone.com/EoSW5z)